# socket programming confusion of getaddrinfo function

Tags: c, network-programming, getaddrinfo

In `getaddrinfo("www.example.net","1234", &hints, &server_info)`

What is the use of the `hints` parameter?

Comment: Via [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo): "hints can be either NULL or an addrinfo structure with the type of service we are interested (ex. a socket can be available for both TCP and UDP so we can assert our interest in the former only)"

Answer (score 1):

`getaddrinfo` is documented in a [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo), which has this to say regarding the hints parameter:

> The hints argument points to an addrinfo structure that specifies
>   criteria for selecting the socket address structures returned in the
>   list pointed to by res. If hints is not NULL it points to an addrinfo
>   structure whose ai_family, ai_socktype, and ai_protocol specify
>   criteria that limit the set of socket addresses returned by
>   getaddrinfo()

So it's a parameter that limits the results based on a given criteria. The criteria is given using a `addrinfo` struct:

```
struct addrinfo {
    int              ai_flags;
    int              ai_family;
    int              ai_socktype;
    int              ai_protocol;
    socklen_t        ai_addrlen;
    struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
    char            *ai_canonname;
    struct addrinfo *ai_next;
};
```

You can read about each of the parameters of the struct on the same man page.